# DateTime format according to the culture in MVC

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, culture

I have an MVC view where I list a dateTime type column named "CreatedOn", the values are formatted like this: '**DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS**', 
When I click on edit link to modify a value I obtain the same format,

When I modify the edited value I get the validation error: "**The field CreatedOn must be a date.**"

My EF model class maps this field as DateTime type.

My database collation is **French_CI**, the field in the sql server table is smalldatetime type,
when I open the table to see the field format I find it like '**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**'

I verified the default application culture and found "fr-FR", then I added in the web.config file the next code:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" culture="fr-FR" />
</system.web>
```

But the issue still remain the same, any idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Validate doesn't understand cultures.

I believe for dates, it just calls the javascript: `new Date(value)`.

You can fix this with a globalization plugin and a bit of javascript.

Microsoft wrote a globalization plugin here: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Then you want to replace the validation method with something like this:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value);
}
```

You probably also want to replace the other methods for numbers etc. - have a look at the bottom of `jquery.validate.js` for examples.

Comment: Using "Manage Nugget Package" in Visual Studio, I have installed Globalize and Moon.Validation for jQuery validation nuggets, are they enough to resolve this issue or have I to use the updated plugin contained in your link above?

Comment: Just installed Globalize and Moon.Validation for jQuery validation nuggets, and replaced the validation method for dates with `Globalize.parseDate(value)` in `jquery.validate.js` and it worked, thank you.

Comment: If only they had a Globalise.parseDate as well :)