# Setting up the Globalize Nuget package

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I am trying to install Globalize to resolve an issue I desribe here: [Validation failing because of date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169314/validation-failing-because-of-date-format). Please see Christopher Thrower answer.

How do I add `globalize.js` and `jquery.val.globalize.js` to `bundles/jqueryval`?

`bundles/jqueryval` currently looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

The path to the two files is:

```
c:\application\packages\jquery-globalize.1.0.0\content\Scripts\globalize.js
c:\application\packages\jquery-globalize.1.0.0\content\Scripts\jquery.validate
```

The path to the MVC scripts folder is:

c:\application\mvc\scripts

Also what is meant by: `~/` in the path. I can find no documentation.

Comment: `~/` gets translated to the root of the web application, so in this case `~/scripts` means `c:\application\mvc\scripts` for example.

Comment: @DavidG, how do I get to: globalize.js ?

Comment: If the Nuget package hasn't copied the js file into your web project folder, then you will need to do this manually. Also, perhaps send a message to the project maintainer about it

Comment: @DavidG, do you know how to setup this Globalize package? I am pulling my hair out.  The documentation is very comprehensive but explains nothing in my opinion.

Comment: I have no idea, never used that package (and you haven't linked to it so I can't even take a look!)

Comment: @DavidG, it is here: https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize

Answer (score 1):

Having taken a look at the package I can see that it installs the relevant Javascript files directly into your web project. So if you take a look you will see something like this:

[image: Project Layout]

So to add it to your app, it should be as simple as

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
    "~/Scripts/globalize.js"));
```

Comment: I have done that.  However, it appears to do nothing.  Absolutely nothing.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Please see my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169314/validation-failing-because-of-date-format

Comment: No, I'm not going to do that. The question needs to be self contained. You asked how to add the js files to your bundle and I answered that. How you use the library is now up to you.